# How difficult is it to start freelancing while attending university?

Tags: web-development, working-from-home, programmer

I am an 18-year-old boy who will be educating in university soon. I wondered if there is anybody who started freelancing besides studying. By freelancing I don't mean a big business, but **using typical skills** like typing, using front-end for web creation, or even translating content... and so on. Just to gain some more money for living - universities over here don't support students as well as many regions.

**How difficult is it to start freelancing while attending university?** Is this going to be very hard or cause some problems in my education? Or on the contrary, it will be very cool and it works out?

If anyone has tried freelancing while attending secondary education, how did it go? I heard that like 60% of freelancers start their business as a second job at first, and after that it becomes real. So I guessed this situation may be like mine when I'm studying (it's my first job) and working as a freelancer (my second job).

Answers should be supported by experience or other evidence. In addition, I would also appreciate advice on what to do and what not to do.

Comment: We can't answer as the situation depends on the school, your capabilities, and numerous other factors. The only way to find the answer is to ask the school and to actually try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If being a freelancer is your dream, then try doing it as a part-time job while studying.

Start on small projects to build your skills and experience in the area, join a freelancing platform such as Upwork, Freelancer.

A lot depends on what you want to start your freelance career in, what skills and qualifications you already have. The best thing is to get some experience in the field where you want to freelance.

It does not affect your study, but don't just go into it blindly first - main focus is on your study.

My experience as a freelancer is that to many computer science majors, freelancing can seem mysterious and hard to get into. I initially thought my computer science skills were not good enough to charge people for my service, but then I got help from everywhere and managed to grow in freelancing.

Answer (score 2):

**Advantages:**

1. You can add your Work in your Resume (by asking for permission from client)
2. You will get exposure to real world problems
3. Your soft and hard skills will develop

**Disadvantage:**

1. If you fail in Time management then your grades will affect directly (so dedicate not more than 4 hr a day)
2. If you get stuck in big project then there is no return path (so take small project in beginning)

**Suggestion:**
Just give it a try but simultaneously focus on academics too